# Finding the values last values of a key in HashMap in Scala - how to write it in a functional style

Tags: scala

I want to search the hashmap after a key and if the key is found give me the last value of the found value of the key. Here is my solution so far:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

object Tmp extends Application {
  val hashmap = new HashMap[String, String]
  hashmap += "a" -> "288 | object | L"

  def findNameInSymboltable(name: String) = {
    if (hashmap.get(name) == None)
      "N"
    else
      hashmap.get(name).flatten.last.toString
  }

  val solution: String = findNameInSymboltable("a")
  println(solution) // L

}
```

Is there maybe a functional style of it which save me the overhead of locs?

Comment: Why don"t you store a Seq in your map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couldn't quite get your example to work. But maybe something like this would do the job?

```
hashmap.getOrElse("a", "N").split(" | ").last
```

The "getOrElse" will at least save you the if/else check.

Comment: Gotta love the terseness of Scala.

Comment: Yup, love this kind of syntactic sugar and learned something very useful.

Answer (score 0):

In case your `"N"` is intended for display and not for computation, you can drag ouround the fact that there is no such `"a"` in a `None` until display:

```
val solution = // this is an Option[String], inferred
  hashmap.get("a"). // if None the map is not done
    map(_.split(" | ").last) // returns an Option, perhaps None
```

Which can alse be written:

```
val solution = // this is an Option[String], inferred
  for(x <- hashmap.get("a"))
    yield {
      x.split(" | ").last
    }
```

And finally:

```
println(solution.getOrElse("N"))
```